# Vue-argon don't render any component

Tags: vue.js

Browser's console image

[image: 1]

I install and run `npm run serve` and running on local but the app just render nothing, in console, 'app' div doesn't contain any component. I followed the document but it's not working.

this is main.js file

```
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import router from './router';
import ArgonDashboard from './plugins/argon-dashboard';
import 'element-plus/lib/theme-chalk/index.css';

const app = createApp(App);
app.use(router);
app.use(ArgonDashboard);
app.mount('#app');
```

and this is the router. file
[router file image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8pCrP.jpg)
what should i do or what can I fix for the issue

Comment: I believe more info is needed to be provided but seeing main.js no one can tell what is going on :)

Comment: uhm i added the image of router file (index.js). Because terminal and console don't show any error so I just couldn't know there's any errors

Comment: Instead of providing images, provide the code in the text format. I would prefer to follow this- https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask